# Swift 2: understanding AnyObject and Self

Tags: swift, protocols

I couldn't find any good explanation to my questions so I'd like to ask you directly. First of all I'd like to refine my code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31270708/4572536).

My problem is the protocol `AnyObject` and the `Self` type. I didn't implement `AnyObject` into my code because it is marked with `@objc` and I don't want any Objective-C stuff involved in my code (don't judge me for that). I also couldn't find any explanation about the `Self` type. It just worked as expected, but Xcode does not replace `Self` with the type the static function is called at.

Here is some example:

```
extension Int : Instance {}

Int.singleton { (customInstanceName) -> Self in 0 } // Self shall be replaced with Int
```

As you can see Xcode produces a Self instead an Int. Is there any chance I could fix this? Am I right that Self does return the dynamicType and my implementation is fine as it is in my post above? I would really appreciate any good explanation about the `Self` type.

As you have seen in my code. I am using a custom protocol to check whether my instance is a class or not. Is there any other shiny implementation to check my instances if they are classes or structure types, or am I forced to use `AnyObject` if I want to get rid of my ClassInstance protocol?

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE:**

```
protocol Test {}

class A : Test {}

struct B : Test {}

let aClass : Test = A()
let aStruct : Test = B()

if let someClass = aClass as? AnyObject {
    print(someClass) // only this will print
}

if let someStruct = aStruct as? AnyObject {
    print(someStruct)
}
```

This will work, but `AnyObject` is still marked as an `@objc` protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Self` type can be only used in protocols where it is a implicit `typealias` of the type which conforms to it:

```
protocol Testable {
    func test() -> Self
}
```

If you want to conform to this protocol you than have to replace `Self` with the name of the type. For instance:

```
struct Product: Testable {
    func test() -> Product {
        return Product()
    }
}
```

**Important Edit:**

As DevAndArtist pointed out in the comments there is a working class check in Swift 1.2 (without automatic bridging to Objective C) but not Swift 2 (Xcode 7 beta 3; probably a bug):

```
if instance.dynamicType is AnyClass {
    // instance is a class
} else {
    // instance is not a class
}
```

You can see workaround (mainly) for Swift 2 below.

**End Edit**

With respect to classes you should use `AnyObject` if you want to keep it simple but you can also use reflection which would be much more effort.

Below you can see some reflection results of string interpolations (only the first few characters):

```
"\(reflect(classType))"                  // Swift._ClassMirror
"\(reflect(0))"                          // Swift._LeafMirror
"\(reflect(enumType))"                   // Swift._EnumMirror
"\(reflect(structure))"                  // Swift._StructMirror
"\(reflect([0, 4]))"                     // Swift._ArrayTypeMirror
"\(reflect(NSDate()))"                   // Foundation._NSDateMirror
"\(reflect(NSURLRelationship.Contains))" // Swift._EnumMirror
"\(reflect(Int?(2)))"                    // Swift._OptionalMirror
```

As you can see enums are consistent if they are not defined in the Swift standard library (unfortunately also Optional...). So you can distinguish also structs and enums:

```
public enum Type {
    case Enum, Class, Struct
}

public func getType<T>(anything: T) -> Type {
    if anything is AnyObject {
        return .Class
    }
    if "\(reflect(anything))".hasPrefix("Swift._EnumMirror") {
        return .Enum
    }
    return .Struct
}
```

So for a better result you have to put some effort into it to differentiate between all the different cases.

But the easiest way to distinguish only between reference types and value types (aka classes and structs/enums) is still (unfortunately only works for own declared structs and not built in types because they can be bridged to Objective C; I'm working on it...):

```
if instance is AnyObject {}

// or: if instance is of type Any
if let classInstance = instance as? AnyObject {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd love to see a clear example how to use reflections to check whether my instance is a structure or a class. I never used them before. It's a pity that we can not do something like this: `guard let classInstance = instance is class else { /**/ }`. The explanation about the `Self` is clear to me now. Thx :) I hope apple will fix the issue with protocols default implementation and `Self` so Xcode will use the right type automatically.

Comment: I post the code soon. It should be `guard let classInstance = instance as? class else { /**/ }` :)

Comment: `as?` or `is` it doesn't matter here (yet). Sure both has it specific meanings, but you've got the point. :D But it would be nice if this could work. Take your time, I'm not in rush.

Comment: Thank you :) It is a solution for my problem, but I guess it just adds a bit more overhead as if I would only try to downcast my instance to the `@objc protocol AnyObject`. Anyways thx, this helped.

Comment: Here is a solution to my previous problem: `guard instance.dynamicType is AnyObject.Type else {}`. This will only pass if it's a class and it won't bridge structure types to objc types. :)

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't work for me (Xcode 7 beta 3). It is always true even with user defined structs and enums. Did I made something wrong?

Comment: Your fine here, try it with Swift 1.2 and you'll see. In Swift 2.0 it's just a bug ;) Should hopefully be fixed with the stable release.

Comment: I just remembered that there is also a typealias `AnyClass` for `AnyObject.Type` so the more gentle solution would look like this: `guard instance.dynamicType is AnyClass else { /**/ }`