# How to create Singleton in generic class?

Tags: swift

I have been trying to convert a singleton class to generic. Since swift doesn't support stored property in generic class Singleton could not be implemented. I tried all the possible solutions that I know but nothing works. Other Stackoverflow answers related to this topic doesn't help either.

I have added the sample code below.

```swift
class SingleTonClass<T: Equatable & RawRepresentable>: NSObject where T.RawValue == String {
    private var catlog: CatlogModelClass<T>?
    private var catlogArray = [CatlogModelClass<T>]()
    
    
    // This stored property now has to be changed to support Generic
    private static var shared : SingleTonClass = {
        return SingleTonClass()
    }()

    // Accessor for Singleton
    static func sharedInstance() -> SingleTonClass {
       return shared
    }

    private override init () {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be non-singleton, you need to create a public constructor.

You should pass in the catalog and catalogArray into the constructor and initialize self.catalog and self.catalogArray. You then need to remove the static shared instance of the class, because your new setup would require you to create an instance of it.

Comment: This has to be a singleton class as per the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I've been inspired by that solution [Creating a generic singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570027/creating-a-generic-singleton)

and this worked for me

```swift
import Foundation

class Singleton {
    static private var instances = [String: AnyObject]()
    
    static func getInstance<T: AnyObject>(_ objectType: T.Type, instance: () -> T) -> T {
        let name = NSStringFromClass(objectType)
        if let instance = instances[name] as? T {
            return instance
        }
        let instance = instance()
        instances[name] = instance
        return instance
    }
}

class Generic<T> {
    var value: T?
    
    private init() { }
    
    static func getInstance() -> Generic<T> {
        Singleton.getInstance(Generic<T>.self) {
            Generic<T>()
        }
    }
}
```